# Log4j show package name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

Right now for my ConversionPattern I have:

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

What I'd like to do is also include the full package name with the class (%F:%L) but I can't find [any config to do so in the docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html). I do understand that this will be slower, but it's only for debugging and not when the system will be in production.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe I just misunderstand you, but %C will output your class with package.

From your referenced docs:

%C

> Used to output the fully qualified
>   class name of the caller issuing the
>   logging request. This conversion
>   specifier can be optionally followed
>   by precision specifier, that is a
>   decimal constant in brackets.
>
> If a precision specifier is given,
>   then only the corresponding number of
>   right most components of the class
>   name will be printed. By default the
>   class name is output in fully
>   qualified form.
>
> For example, for the class name
>   "org.apache.xyz.SomeClass", the
>   pattern %C{1} will output "SomeClass".
>
> WARNING Generating the caller class
>   information is slow. Thus, use should
>   be avoided unless execution speed is
>   not an issue.

**Update:**
In many cases you can use %c also, which will print out the full class with package also, if your category is your class-name. For example when your doing stuff like this when initializing your Log:

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClazz.class);
```

Using %c is not slow.

Comment: That would be it!! I completely missed it. Doh.

Answer (score 2):

Using `C{1}` is slow. Please see the details below:

As per the following [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html):

> Used to output the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing
>   the logging request. This conversion specifier can be optionally
>   followed by precision specifier, that is a decimal constant in
>   brackets. If a precision specifier is given, then only the
>   corresponding number of right most components of the class name will
>   be printed. By default the class name is output in fully qualified
>   form.
>
> For example, for the class name `org.apache.xyz.SomeClass`, the
>   pattern `%C{1}` will output `SomeClass`.
>
> **WARNING** Generating the caller class information is slow. Thus, use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.