# Log4j multiple configurations within a single web-app

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a web-app which I am trying to work with. I have different services in my web-app. Each provides a unique function but access the same database. Each service communicates with the database, adds or updates stuff, and GUI displays the output. 
I am working with Spring, maven and using mybatis for SQL mapping. I am packaging everything into a war file and deploying it onto Tomcat.

I want each component of the web-app to log SQL queries that it executes. I am using log4j as the logging engine. How can I make each component use different log4j configuration? Can jdbcdslog help me store some metadata related to the queries?

Basically I want to log data into separate log files per component. And log4j picks up only the last configuration file it loads from the components. All other configurations go useless. So I am trying to find a way to separate out the log data per component.

```
    Web-App
       Component1 
       Component2
       Component3
       Component4
```

Comment: Do you call Log4J directly? Or does mybatis do it for you?

Comment: Hi Thilo, In my application, MyBatis does not delegate the call to Log4j. I am using jdbcdslog to log the SQL, which uses slf4j with Log4j as the logging engine. I didn't find Mybatis as a suitable option because I want pure SQL queries that I can copy-paste and directly use it against a database, and look for populated values. MyBatis does show me the queries that are executed, but those are not directly usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a different log4j appender for each of your service package. Here is how you can do this in log4j.xml:

Appender1

```
<category name="com.test.project.Component1" additivity="true">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOG1"/>
</category>
```

Appender2

```
<category name="com.test.project.Component2" additivity="true">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOG2"/>
</category>
```

You can use the same approach for properties file in case you are using properties file configuration for log4j.

Comment: The question is if that is possible when all these components use the same database access library (that presumably does the logging), mybatis in this case.

Comment: @Thilo I am trying to answer this part "Basically I want to log data into separate log files per component. And log4j picks up only the last configuration file it loads from the components. All other configurations go useless. So I am trying to find a way to separate out the log data per component."

Comment: @JunedAhsan, Thank you for your reply. Could you also suggest me a way to acquire metadata related to a query, like which package the query was fired from. I want to store the data with respect to a package into Log files. When the war is deployed all the Log data is just dumped into Log files. Can I know where it came from?

Comment: @harshalvaidya You need to use %C to print the package and class name with each log line. Read more here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html and also follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594818/log4j-show-package-name

Comment: @JunedAhsan, I tried to use the %C parameter to print the package. But the problem is I get something like                          2013-07-30-main--INFO -org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger:java.sql.Statement.executeQuery: SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees;                               For the sql query which I tried to get logged. It does not give me the class which it was fired from, since I am using jdbcdslog for logging the SQL.

Comment: @JunedAhsan the problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954848/get-the-name-of-the-package-from-which-a-sql-query-was-fired